# Poco Timer with callback from same class

Tags: c++, timer, poco

I have a simple class which uses Poco Timer:

```
MyClass::MyClass(){
 Timer timer(250,5000);
 TimerCallback<MyClass> callback(*this, &MyClass::onTimer);
 timer.start(callback);
}

MyClass::onTimer(){
  cout <<"Tick"<<endl;
}
```

Obviously, the code for callback initialization is incorrect. What is the correct way to call a function from within the same class (this) with TimerCallback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Timer` as member of `MyClass`:

```
MyClass {
  //...
  Timer timer;
};
```

then construct `timer` object on initialization list to set intervals in ctor of `Timer`

```
MyClass::MyClass() : timer(250,5000) { // <--
  TimerCallback<MyClass> callback(*this, &MyClass::onTimer);
  timer.start(callback);
}
```

or use `setPeriodicInterval` and `setStartInterval`

```
  MyClass::MyClass() {
   timer.setStartInterval(500);
   timer.setPeriodicInterval(2500);
   TimerCallback<MyClass> callback(*this, &MyClass::onTimer);
   timer.start(callback);
  }
```

Comment: Great, it worked, thanks. It appears my code was almost fine, but it was missing the Timer& timer variable in the onTimer() function.

Comment: Yeh, you are right, `onTimer` method should have signature `onTimer(Poco::Timer&)` I didn't see it, my mistake.